# Optional Sampling Theorem Application

Tags: brownian-motion

Let x, y > 0. Defint eh first passage time of a Brownian motion $W_t$ as $\tau_a$ = min{t $\ge$ 0: $W_t$ = a}. I need to show that E[$e^{-u\tau_x}$$1_{\tau_x < \tau_{-y}}$] = $\frac{sinh(y\sqrt{2u})}{sinh((x + y)\sqrt{2u}}$.

My method, and the only method that I will be able to understand, is to use the optional sampling theorem. I noted that $Z_t = e^{\theta W_t - \frac{1}{2}\theta^{2}t}$ is martingale and that the optional sampling theorem states that $E[Z_{\tau_{min\, {a, t}}}$] = 1. Applying this to the stopping time $ {\tau_x, \wedge \tau_{-y}}$ I have managed to show that as t --> $\infty$ $Z_(\tau_x\wedge\tau_{-y})\wedge t$ = $e^{-\theta y - \frac{1}{2} \theta^2 \tau_{-y}}$$1_{\tau_{-y} \,  < \,   \tau_x}$ + $e^{\theta x - \frac{1}{2} \theta^2 \tau_{x}}$$1_{\tau_{x} \,  < \,   \tau_{-y}}$. I can't figure where to go from here. I had a similar problem, but there was only one level involved, where here we have two: x and y.

I believe we should now take the expectation of the expression I derived and set it equal to one by optional sampling theorem, but I don't know what follows. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already shown above,
\begin{align*}
1 = E\Big(e^{-\theta y - \frac{1}{2}\theta^2 \tau_{-y} }1_{\tau_{-y}<\tau_x} \Big)+E\Big(e^{\theta x - \frac{1}{2}\theta^2 \tau_{x} }1_{\tau_x < \tau_{-y}} \Big).
\end{align*}
Set $\theta = \sqrt{2u}$, we obtain that
\begin{align*}
1 = E\Big(e^{-\sqrt{2u}y - u \tau_{-y} }1_{\tau_{-y}<\tau_x} \Big)+E\Big(e^{\sqrt{2u} x - u \tau_{x} }1_{\tau_x < \tau_{-y}} \Big),
\end{align*}
that is,
\begin{align*}
e^{\sqrt{2u}y} = E\Big(e^{- u \tau_{-y} }1_{\tau_{-y}<\tau_x} \Big)+e^{\sqrt{2u} (x+y)}E\Big(e^{ - u \tau_{x} }1_{\tau_x < \tau_{-y}} \Big).
\end{align*}
On the other hand, by setting $\theta = -\sqrt{2u}$, we obtain that
\begin{align*}
1 = E\Big(e^{\sqrt{2u}y - u \tau_{-y} }1_{\tau_{-y}<\tau_x} \Big)+E\Big(e^{-\sqrt{2u} x - u \tau_{x} }1_{\tau_x < \tau_{-y}} \Big),
\end{align*}
that is,
\begin{align*}
e^{-\sqrt{2u}y} = E\Big(e^{- u \tau_{-y} }1_{\tau_{-y}<\tau_x} \Big)+e^{-\sqrt{2u} (x+y)}E\Big(e^{ - u \tau_{x} }1_{\tau_x < \tau_{-y}} \Big).
\end{align*}
Consequently,
\begin{align*}
e^{\sqrt{2u}y} - e^{-\sqrt{2u}y} = \big[e^{\sqrt{2u} (x+y)} - e^{-\sqrt{2u} (x+y)} \big]E\Big(e^{ - u \tau_{x} }1_{\tau_x < \tau_{-y}} \Big).
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
E\Big(e^{ - u \tau_{x} }1_{\tau_x < \tau_{-y}} \Big) = \frac{\sinh (\sqrt{2u}y)}{\sinh \big(\sqrt{2u} (x+y) \big)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: From Wikipedia: $\sinh x = \frac {e^x - e^{-x}} {2}$, please show the final steps of your solution.

Comment: I have added one more intermediate step.

Comment: How do you eliminate the first expectation in $e^{-\sqrt{2u}y} = E\Big(e^{- u \tau_{-y} }1_{\tau_{-y}<\tau_x} \Big)+e^{-\sqrt{2u} (x+y)}E\Big(e^{ - u \tau_{x} }1_{\tau_x < \tau_{-y}} \Big).
$?

Comment: It is eliminated by a difference with $e^{\sqrt{2u}y} = E\Big(e^{- u \tau_{-y} }1_{\tau_{-y}<\tau_x} \Big)+e^{\sqrt{2u} (x+y)}E\Big(e^{ - u \tau_{x} }1_{\tau_x < \tau_{-y}} \Big)$.

Comment: This is correct, but I had already worked this out a while back, if you see my identical posting on math.stackexchange I mention that I had found the solution. Indeed I did it exactly as you did it. Despite the late answer, +1.